# Iterate over rows in pandas and insert values in another cell of the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a 'Reviews' column and an empty 'Pos' column.

[image]

My task is to calculate the positive sentiment of each review and insert it into the adjacent 'Pos' column. I thought of something like below but it's not working. Please suggest a solution.

```
 for review in df['Reviews']:
        blob = TextBlob(review, analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())
        sent_p = blob.sentiment.p_pos
        df['Pos'].values[i] = sent_p
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: if your sent_p is the exact value to assign , then use  df.loc[i,'Pos'] = sent_p in line 4

Comment: @NagaKiran thanks, it works.